# Google's Play Asset Delivery Build aab File in Unity too large

Tags: unity, google-play, google-play-services, build-process, build

I want to upload an aab file from my unity project to my play console account, but unfortunately, my file was rejected because it's size is larger than the 150MB threshold limit for aab on google play store.

Then while looking for a solution, I found out that obb files are now made obsolete and I could use google's Play Asset Delivery system to upload my file. So then I followed the "not so clear" instructions on how to use the PAD system in Unity, I made an asset bundle that contains all my font asset(because that was what increased my aab from 120MB to 260MB), and added it to the Asset Delivery Settings in Unity and selected "Separate Base APK Asset". Then I built the aab file using PAD(by clicking Google > Build Android App Bundle), and my generated aab went from 260MB to 680MB.

Why did the size increase enormously? Isn't the point of it to reduce the size on the aab so that it can be accepted by play? Am I missing something or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Have you found any solution for it?

Comment: I found a work around. Instead of packing asset bundles, I packed addressable asset packs using this:
https://killertee.wordpress.com/2021/09/04/unity-play-asset-delivery-and-addressable-assets/

Comment: @MetaMax I'd say that's worth writing up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround:
https://killertee.wordpress.com/2021/09/04/unity-play-asset-delivery-and-addressable-assets/

It uses unity's addressables package with google's play asset delivery and not asset bundles.

Comment: This is currently a link-only answer, which will become useless if the link rots in the future. Can you edit your post to describe the workaround in more depth, so that information is preserved even if the link becomes inaccessible for a future reader?

Answer (score 0):

If you're relying on Unity only to use PAD (Play Asset Delivery), Unity's solution has problems and doesn't assemble the AAB properly, basically, it will get everything you have in your StreamingAssets folder and that will be packed in an asset pack + it will keep the StreamingAssets stuff in the base.apk archive, making your final AAB and APKS at least double the size it should be or more.
In order to use PAD properly, you should follow up on Google's explanations about it here https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery and come up with your own version of what Google suggests, I say it because I just finished our own PAD solution in my company and I ended up writing stuff for Runtime, Editor and Build on Unity. It's all working as expected for us. Google's plain solution for Unity is no silver-bullet either, it will probably just work for a fraction of projects out there.